# Convert SQL to DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql, doctrine-query

I need to change this `sql` query to doctrine query or `dql` form. Is this possible?

```
SELECT count(*) AS listenCount, l.post_id AS postId 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ll.user_id, ll.post_id FROM listen ll) l  
WHERE l.post_id IN (' . $id . ') 
GROUP BY  l.post_id
```

My problem is with the text inside the parentheses in front of "`FROM`", which needs to be the class name in `dql`. But I can not give it a class name, because of the `DISTINCT` command.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent SQL for your query can be rewritten as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS listenCount, 
l.post_id AS postId 
FROM listen l  
WHERE l.post_id IN (' . $id . ') 
GROUP BY  l.post_id
```

In doctrine i assume you have setup your listen entity which contains mappings for user entity and post entity so you can write equivalent DQL for above query as below

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS listenCount, 
p.id AS postId 
FROM YourBundle:listen l
JOIN l.user u 
JOIN l.post  p
WHERE p.id IN (' . $id . ') 
GROUP BY  p.id
```

> Note SQL query just gets the result without using joins for user and post table but in DQL you will need join part for both entities

Even better approach would be select post entity and then do the joining part, also note i assume your post entity has a mapping for listen entity named as listen

```
SELECT p,COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS listenCount, 
FROM YourBundle:post p
JOIN p.listen  l
JOIN l.user u 
WHERE p.id IN (' . $id . ') 
GROUP BY  p.id
```